# Adjust UICollectionViewCell to fit content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a label that is set to resize to its content. I want the UICollectionViewCell to do the same. I cannot find anyway to implement that.

A picture describing my current arrangement can be found below:

[image]

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll want to implement the [UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/index.html) method [collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout/collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:) to adjust the size of each collection item based on the contents.

[Here's a tutorial on Collection Views](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iPhone_iOS_6_Storyboard-based_Collection_View_Tutorial) that covers [this specific topic](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iPhone_iOS_6_Storyboard-based_Collection_View_Tutorial#Setting_Sizes_for_Cell_Items).

Comment: `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath: ` just allows you set size dynamically in points, it has nothing to do with height based on content

Comment: Also I have 2 sections in UIControllerView (2 columns). Two cells in one row should have the same size even if their size content is different (something like this is implemented in Android natively when using RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager, very easy)

Answer (score 1):

configure collection:

```
YOU_Collection.layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
```

and in cell add label constraints (top and bottom)

Answer (score 0):

Use "Autolayout" in cell's Interface Builder document. After setting constraints, your cell frame is going to dynamically change.
[image]

Comment: it's not true: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55676984/make-uicollectionviewcells-height-match-its-content-sum-height-of-all-sub-view